# If the server on my mac is not running for MySQL, is can I try to run other databases on my machine?

Tags: mysql, server

I have a java project which connects to a  MySQL database. Earlier it was working fine, but I think I messed up some of the configuration settings when trying to connect not via localhost. After messing around for hours and not making any progress (including completely reinstalling MySQL onto my mac and pc ( I was trying to connect these) ) I have given up and now am thinking of using some other database software like Postgre. Will the same error come up since its to do with not being able to connect as the server is not running? 
The error at the moment is:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Please:

1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3. Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Comment: Did you check all those 4 steps? I use windows and in my case sometimes the mySql service doesnt start automatic, and have to go to the `services` panel to start it manually. BTW All db can have same problems, so dont try to run when you have something wrong.

Comment: We can't check these 4 steps for you. Tell us what is wrong exacly, then we can provide better advice.

Comment: I have tried my best. number 4 is fine for sure. It says the server isn't running, but when I tried it on a PC I went though services, and it wouldn't let me select an option to restart, stop or play..